# Sine Gordon model in 3+1 Dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, klein-gordon-equation, sine-gordon

I'm have read the publication of

Neuenhahn, C. and Marquardt, F. (2015) ‘Quantum simulation of expanding space–time with tunnel-coupled condensates’, New Journal of Physics. IOP Publishing, 17(12), p. 125007

here the authors had set up an experiment of coupled 1D Bose-Einstein-Condensates and drew parallels between this coupled Bose-Einstein-Condensates and the expansion of the universe. This idea is not revolutionary new since the authors in https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05800 had a very similar idea. But the question I am asking myself is if, for example, the Sine Gordon model coupled to the Einstein equations (let's say in a FRW metric setting) would be a "good" model of the universe. I mean is it somewhere written up that is plausible or there are some hints that such a model of the universe would be a good candidate for our universe.

Maybe anyone has some interesting publications or some own ideas on that.

Cheers

Comment: So to be clear, you're looking for papers that discuss the Sine Gordon Eq in the context of inflationary cosmology?

Comment: Yeah that would be nice